# C# My code is not doing math.. it is just sticking the numbers together

Tags: c#, console

I am creating a friendly ai whose name is Phil ;), but I need it to be able to do math. I did try, and I also tried **+=**, but it wont work. For example, if I did 1+1, instead of 2, it would give me 11. Here is my code:

```
namespace Game
{
    public static class Program
    {

        //commands
        public static string enteredCommand;
        public static string commanddomath = "doMath";

        //Math command stuff
        public static string MathOperation;
        public static string FirstOperatorNumber;
        public static string SecondOperatorNumber;
        public static string FinalAwnser;

        static void Main()
        {
           if (enteredCommand == "doMath")
           {
            Console.WriteLine("Ok");
            Console.WriteLine("What Operation should I do?");
            MathOperation = Console.ReadLine();
            if (MathOperation == "+")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Addition! Easy! What is the first number? ex. 6");
                FirstOperatorNumber = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Ok, what do you want the second number to be? ex. 8");
                SecondOperatorNumber = Console.ReadLine();
                FinalAwnser = FirstOperatorNumber + SecondOperatorNumber;
                Console.WriteLine("Ok! The awnser is..." + FinalAwnser);
            }
           }
           else
           {
            Console.WriteLine("That is not a command");
           }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: You are "adding" strings, that is concatenating them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/concatenate-multiple-strings#-and--operators. Your program cannot guess these strings represent numbers, and you want to add these numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are storing the user's input (`FirstOperatorNumber` and `SecondOperatorNumber`) as strings. The addition operator (`+`), when applied to two strings, performs an operation called **concatenation**: it adds the characters from each string to form another string.

But you want **addition**, which is the result of the addition operator being used on two *integers*. So you must store the user's input as an integer by replacing 'string' with 'int' in the variable declaration:

```cs
public static int FirstOperatorNumber;
public static int SecondOperatorNumber;
```

The input will still be a string, so you need to convert it as well, like this:

```cs
FirstOperatorNumber = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```